# bin/ld: cannot find -lnode: No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, linux, build, arm, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross build a library for different environment than host using ffi-napi.

When I do `npm install --target-arch=arm` I get the following error.

Following environment is used.

platform: Ubuntu 22
cross compiler: arm-linux-gnueabihf
node: 12.22.9 | linux |x64

**Error**

```
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lnode: No such file or directory
npm ERR! collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
npm ERR! make: *** [ffi_bindings.target.mk:149: Release/obj.target/ffi_bindings.node] Error 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/share/nodejs/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:276:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 6.5.0-14-generic
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/share/nodejs/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /home/thales/Downloads/demo2/node_modules/ffi-napi
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v12.22.9
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
```

Here is the package.json file I am using to install

```
{
  "name": "demo2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ref-napi": "^2.0.1",
    "ffi-napi": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

It should install all dependencies.

Comment: in Node 12 configuration file -lnode was present. Removing it worked :)